# Gulp watch doesn't recompile

Tags: gulp

I have a task :

```
gulp.task('styles', ['cleanup'], function () { 
'use strict';
log('Compiling Less files to :' + config.temp);

return gulp
    .src(config.less)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%']}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.temp));
});
```

This tasks works like it should when I call it manually. It deletes the files in config.temp (not shown in code snippet) and recompiles the less to css and places it again in config.temp directory.

The problem is when I try to run this task inside gulp.watch :

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(config.less, ['styles']); 
});
```

The task doens't work anymore. I can see gulp picking up changes I make in my less files, I see the log output, there are no errors, yet still the task hasn't really happend. My css output remains the same.

Another indication that the tasks aren't really executed, is the time that gulp spend; when I do it manually it takes longer :

[image: Gulp styles manual]

then when the gulp watch runs the same task :

[image]

I have been following a tutorial that does the exact same thing, and I have some example files that also use gulp.watch and work.

I have seen some mentioning of gulp-watch but I'm not sure that's the same as gulp.watch?

Hope it's some obvious mistake someone can point out to me.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it like this?  https://hansrwindhoff.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/debugging-task-runner-tasks-like-gulp-with-visual-studio-code-editordebugger/

Comment: I also have a section in my VS Code course that shows how to do this (debug gulp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I could just delete this question because apparently there is nothing wrong: Webstorm was just too bloody slow in refreshing itself, so I always thought the .css file hadn't changed. I just needed to wait approx 45 seconds. Sorry for wasting internet space!

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

1. Try the debugging i mentioned in the comments
2. Add this in the `styles` task, right after you pipe in the source code.
   `.pipe($.plumber()) // exit gracefully if something fails after this`

also, make sure you check your version of the gulp.